# INSERT query OleDB C#

Tags: c#, insert, oledb

I know it was 1000000000 times already, but none solution helped to me.
**I want to** insert data in C# using OleDB. I tried mln solutions but here is the easiest one which should work but it doesn't:

```
 SQLCONNECTION = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\dbScenariusz.mdb";

 using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(SQLCONNECTION))
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO Table (content) VALUES('lala')";
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
```

SQLCONNECTION is ok. It works fine for the SELECT query.

*string sql* - I tried this query in Access and it works fine.

I get **no error**. It just didn't insert anything to the database. 
When I run the query in Access (the same database) the row is inserted.

The strange thing is that *command.ExecuteNonQuery();* returns 1! That means that 1 row was affected!

I really have no idea where the problem is, so I really appreciate any help.
Sorry for my english.

**UPDATE:** Another strange thing. I change query to update and it works fine! really wtf? :)

Comment: just a guess, as your code seems fine. are you running it on a 64 bit system?

Comment: Are u sure You're working on the good file ?

Comment: Well Zitun, 1) I insert the row through Microsoft Access (using the same query) 2) I open the table in Visual Studio and I see the row inserted through Access! But the same thing doesn't work in Visual. I really have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are connecting to the DataDirectory. Is the .mbd file being copied after the build? In other words are you re-deploying the database with each build and thereby losing the inserts?

A quick test could be using the same code and same connection to do a select **after** the insert.

Comment: I hoped this is the problem but no. 
1) I run insert query and get return value=1 (1 row affected) 2) I run select query (from the same table) with success 3) I check the table and nothing was inserted 4) Unbelievable!

Comment: You were right Erno! Here is the problem: I've got the database in the main directory, the .mdb file is copied to bin/Debug/ and all changes are made on this file. So when I run the application again all changes in database are gone. How should I change it?

Comment: Simply by not redeploying the database every single time and placing the database in a directory that doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 2):

In the solution Explorer, check `app.config`. Double click the `app.config`, then re-enter the `connectionString`. Give the path of your database.
For example, in my project the default location of connectionString is:

> connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\database.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"

Suppose the database is stored in this location:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Amuk\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\insertion\insertion\App_Data

therefore, replace the connectionString with

> connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Amuk\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\insertion\insertion\App_Data\database.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"

your problem will be solved, i hope this will definitely help you, i was also getting the same problem, and by replacing the `connectionString` with original path, the database is storing all records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use transaction to commit your changes.

```
command.Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(); //after connection.open()
```

Then add

```
command.Transaction.Commit(); //Before connection.close()
```

Comment: I did exactly like you suggested but nothing has changed.

Comment: @arczi - Have you checked properly? There are no errors at all? Apart from this, I dont think there is any issue with your code.

Comment: No errors and no warnings.

1) I insert the row through Microsoft Access (using the same query)
2) I open the table in Visual Studio and I see the row inserted through Access!

I really have no idea what's wrong.